# Chrome extension content script is not injecting in to most pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a basic extension that injects an alert script in to every page loaded. But it seems that the script is injecting only to *some* pages (most pages it's not injected in to), and I couldn't find a pattern in how it picks the pages to get injected to.

This is the manifest:

```
  {
        "name": "TestingTest",
        "version": "0.1.1",
        "description": "Testing Tests!",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": ["http://*/", "https://*/"],
                "js": ["content.js"],
                "run_at": "document_end"
            }
        ],
        "background": {
            "page": "background.html"
        },
        "permissions": [
            "tabs",
            "http://*/", "https://*/",
            "cookies"
        ],
        "icons": {
            "16": "my_icon_64.png",
            "32": "my_icon_64.png",
            "48": "my_icon_64.png",
            "128": "my_icon_64.png"
        }
    }
```

and this is `ccontent.js`:

```
alert("content script");
console.log("content script")
```

I'm getting the alert only on a select few pages. The pages that it's injected in to seem to vary if I load the extension in different Chrome profiles.

Comment: Thank you for writing a good question that includes enough code snippets for potential answerers to see the issue quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your content script is probably loading only on pages where the pathname is just `/`. Add an extra `*` at the end of your url patterns:

```
"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
```